# How can I select and scale an edge loop within Blender?

Tags: 3d-meshes, blender

I'm a web developer looking into game development as a hobby for fun and the challenge. I have just started learning blender 2.6. I am currently doing a tutorial at http://cgcookie.com/blender/2010/12/22/modeling-a-building/
at around 9:30 after making loop cuts he scales a column. I cant get the same selection as he did. he has vertices selected but selected the whole loop cut? can someone tell me how to make that selection he did.

Also what setting does he use to display the dimension numbers of his selections?

Comment: Ok so I figured out part of the solution. I can use select edge loop to get the loop but I cant scale it like he does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select edge-loops by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and klicking on an edge. This works both in vertex- and edge-editing mode.

To display the numbers you see in the video, press <kbd>N</kbd>. This will bring up the transform panel in your 3D view. In that panel there's a section called *Mesh display* where you can tick *Edge length*.

The scaling is explained in the video. Hit <kbd>S</kbd> this will cause blender to change into scale-mode. Then you can constrain the scale mode to the X-axis by hitting <kbd>X</kbd>. This also works for `Y` and `Z` and also in "reverse". So if you would like to scale `Z` and `Y` you would use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

He also holds down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> during scaling, so that scales snap to fractions of 1/10th (eg. `1.0`, `1.1`, `1.2` etc.)

Comment: Thanks everything is working. at first I couldn't find them in the panel but once I reloaded it was there. alt+click doest work on simple meshes like the default cube.

Comment: @yamikoWebs yeah, because the default cube doesn't have any loops. It will just select one edge then. If you create loops (using `Ctrl + R`) you can then select these using `Alt + Rightclick`. That's what he does in the video to select the loops.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the tutorial taking it step by step. I suggest reading through it, first. He understandably can't give instructions for every OS at one time, and the slightly different windows keystrokes are given at the end of a stage. Seems a shame the online manual isn't searchable. Would make things so much simpler.

Comment: This is probably better suited as comment to the question. Answers are usually more canonical information suitable for solving the problem. :)